# Is it possible to set BLE Tx power on android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So, I want to know if is it possible to control the BLE power on android when working as central device, can I somehow set the transmission power? I didn't find any examples or documents related. 
Any documents related would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: My answer was the fourth result on Google..

Comment: You might want to explain why you need to set Tx power rather than use RSSI.

Comment: As I understand the RSSI and Tx power can be informed by peripheral advertising, letting the Central device measure the path loss. But I wanted to know the power that Central device is transmitting when sending some data to peripheral.  Can the peripheral read RSSI?

Answer (score 0):

This class allows the changing of Tx power:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.html

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, but I'm trying to set the central power not the peripheral. I assumed that android is working as central. Do you know if it is possible.

Comment: @LucassMeller Yes, by using that class.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood this class.. Isn't AdvertiseSettings only for advertising? I used this class only when I implemented a peripheral app for testing.

Comment: After reading [some](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/TPS.aspx) more [information](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58510/how-to-set-bluetooth-transmit-power) I don't think it is possible to do this using just the Android Bluetooth API.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that too. Thanks for your attention. maybe we can answer this question with this.